# How to resolve the unpicklingerror in loading gensim corpus? - python

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I can save a serialized corpus into `foobar.mm` but when i try to load it, it gives `UnpicklingError`. Loading the dictionary seems fine though. **Anyone knows how to resolve this? And why does this occur?**

```
>>> from gensim import corpora
>>> docs = ["this is a foo bar", "you are a foo"]
>>> texts = [[i for i in doc.lower().split()] for doc in docs]
>>> print texts
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'], ['you', 'are', 'a', 'foo']]

>>> dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
>>> dictionary.save('foobar.dic')
>>> print dictionary
Dictionary(7 unique tokens)
>>> corpora.Dictionary.load('foobar.dic')
<gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary object at 0x329f910>

>>> corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
>>> corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('foobar.mm', corpus)
>>> corpus = corpora.MmCorpus.load('foobar.mm')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 166, in load
    return unpickle(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 492, in unpickle
    return cPickle.load(open(fname, 'rb'))
cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '%'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation at http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#corpus-formats

What you're trying to do is store the corpus in MatrixMarket format (=a text format) and then load it using the [save/load binary interface](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.SaveLoad).

To load a serialized MatrixMarket corpus, simply `corpus = corpora.MmCorpus('foobar.mm')`

Comment: `MmCorpus('foobar.mm')` also fails for me with `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` on line 595 in your `matutils`. My corpus is huge so my index is saved in a separate .mm.index file, which could be causing the problem. I guess it's also possible I have some empty rows in my corpus somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Since `gensim`'s `corpora` (whatever this is) is using `pickle` as the stacktrace reveals, you will only be able to store data of a limited type.  For more details see [What can be pickled and unpickled?](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/node318.html) in the Python docs.

If this does not apply (i. e. if what you want to pickle and unpickle should be picklable) I fear you might have found a bug in the pickle module.  Maybe you then can solve your issue by upgrading to a newer Python version.

Comment: Btw, the line `return cPickle.load(open(fname, 'rb'))` in the `gensim` source lets an open file linger after execution.  Maybe the rest of that code is equally crappy :-/

Comment: This comment's a few years old, but I still think it's important to point out that it's not useful. If you've got issues with the code quality, submit a patch. Don't just moan about it.

Comment: @TimMcNamara You are right, submitting reports on a product helps improve the quality of the product.  To think that any other way of action is "not useful" is wrong, though.  To the developer it also is very important to evaluate the quality of a product in order to figure out whether to use it or to switch to a different product.  That's what my comment is aiming at.